# Insert some multiple records to mysql db using python 3

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I want to insert multiple records to a `mysql db` using `python`. I use `mysql.connector`. but I receive error. when I try to insert a record without formatting it works but multiple line with formatting doesn't! 
I've used `?` instead of `%s` but I still receive this error.

```
   my_nodes = []
   myconnection = mysql.connector.connect(
       host='127.0.0.1', user='root', passwd='1234', db='job_graph1')
   mycursor=myconnection.cursor()
   for nodes in range(1, 33):
       weight = random.randint(0, 100)
       my_record = (nodes, weight, False, False)
       my_nodes.append(my_record)

   sqlqu = "INSERT INTO t_node(n_id,n_weight,is_entry,is_exit) VALUES(%S, %S, %s, %s)"
   mycursor.executemany(sqlqu, my_nodes)
```

the error I receive is:

> Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err)
>   mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Try to make all "s" lowercases. `VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)`

Comment: they changed when I was trying different ways to fix error. I changed them to lowercase but error still exists.

Comment: Ok but `%S` is a mistake. It must be in lowercase. `print("(%s, %S)"%(1, 2))` `ValueError: unsupported format character 'S' (0x53) at index 6`

Comment: you are right. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to remove `%S` in your sql request.
Because it causes this error :

```
print("(%s, %S)"%(1, 2)) 
ValueError: unsupported format character 'S' (0x53) at index 6
```

So instead of `VALUES(%S, %S, %s, %s)` use `VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)`